# Clustering crime data which has {latitude, longitude, crime-type} tuples

Tags: classification, clustering, spatial

I have a data set which has thousands of rows of {latitude, longitude, crime-type} tuples.

Sample Data:

```
41.757366519   -87.642992854   THEFT
41.910469677   -87.585822373   ROBBERY
41.751270452   -87.690708662   BURGLARY
41.757366519   -87.642992854   THEFT
41.757366519   -87.642992854   THEFT
..             ..              ..
..             ..              ..
```

I am trying to cluster these based upon the crime types.

For example, if in any  region, THEFT has a high frequency of occurrence, based on the data set, it should show up as a cluster. I have tried clustering using the lat-long data only, and that does not seem to have any meaning for this crime dataset.

I am fairly new to data mining, and gradually figuring my way out.

How can I cluster the data using the latitude and longitude values based such that the clusters are related to each other through the crime-type? Is there any tool available that can use the lat-long data and cluster them on the crime-type basis? Otherwise, I can even write a script once I understand how this can be done.

Also, has anyone had any previous experience in crime-data-mining? In what other ways can I find interesting patterns from a crime data-set?

Comment: Why do you want *clustering*? If you know the crime types, why not build a classification type model to identify regions associated w/ different crimes?

Comment: @gung : Wouldn't classification be required in case of prediction of future crime in any location? While my requirement is to analyse the past data, see if any particular crime-type cluster exists in any region, and establish possible relations between the crime-type and the demography of the region.

Comment: It doesn't have to be about future prediction. If you want to test for associations b/t demographic variables & crime, you need a statistical model for that (such as logistic or multinomial logistic regression). If you are wondering if crimes cluster spatially, you need a model whose residuals you can test for spatial autocorrelations.

Comment: @gung  Could you please elaborate this: "If you are wondering if crimes cluster spatially, you need a model whose residuals you can test for spatial autocorrelations." I believe this is what I need. Thanks! :)

Comment: I noticed that several sets of your lat long data are identical.  I looked it up and it's one address in Chicago.  So, I'd ask first what sort of data you have - is it all Chicago? All one neighborhood?  Or are they different cities? If so, do you care about neightborhoods?  If they are all Chicago are the addresses, say, police precincts?

Comment: This isn't my specialty, so it is better for others to answer. But there are ways to test if residuals that are closer in space are closer in value than residuals that are further away.

Comment: @PeterFlom Yes, the data has been taken from Chicago's online available crime data. I'd like to perform a similar analysis on the data of different cities (one city at a time).

Answer (score 1):

I know of people who spatially cluster *individual* crime types: see the [CrimeStat documentation](http://www.nij.gov/topics/technology/maps/pages/crimestat.aspx) for a number of applied examples. I don't see much utility in trying to separate different clusters based on the crime type though. Many places are crime generalists, such as a busy commercial area which will have many assaults, robberies, and thefts. These overlapping hot spots would be difficult to separate in any supervised clustering technique.

About the only crime type I might expect this is feasible is *residential* burglary; those hotspots tend to differ from areas of elevated crime due to more people walking around and interacting.

I can see some utility in such a project though. A hotspot that has many different crime types and a hotspot that only has one crime type may require different strategies by the police department to address the crime problems. That might call for *unsupervised* classification though.